# Create a HashSet with duplicate values

Tags: java, hashset

Is there a possibility that HashSet could have duplicate values in case of multiple threads adding items to it?

I'm not looking from modifying the equals or hashcode methods perspective but simply from multithreaded environment.

Comment: A HashSet is not thread-safe so it should not be accessed from multiple threads concurrently without using some sort of lock; is that what you wanted to know, or are you specifically interested from a theoretical standpoint whether concurrent updates can cause duplicate values rather than some other kind of failure?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the circumstances?  Are you seeing this happen?  Does it really matter if this can happen or not if you shouldn't be allowing multiple threads to access the set simultaneously anyway?

Comment: @kaya3 That's exactly my doubt is...to know whether (theoretically) the concurrent updates could lead to duplicates. A sample program/screenshot which you might have come across would help as I tried many times with complex objects but no luck to experience this scenario.

Comment: @Steve Out of curiosity I want to see the usecase of duplicates in hashset due to concurrent additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that `HashSet` could have duplicate values in case of multiple threads adding items to it?

`HashSet` is not a thread-safe class. If you update a `HashSet` from multiple threads without proper synchronization, then the behavior is unspecified, and difficult to predict.  (And Java version dependent, given that the implementation of `HashSet` has changed a number of times over the lifetime of Java SE.)

The unspecified behavior *could* include duplicates appearing in the set as observed via the set's iterator.

If you want to share a (mutable) set between multiple threads, either use a `ConcurrentHashSet` or a `Collections.synchronizedSet` wrapper or an explicit `Lock` or mutex to synchronize operations.

(The different alternatives all have caveats associated with them.  We can't recommend a specific alternative based on the limited information you have given.)

Comment: This makes sense and all I want is to reproduce this in some way.

Comment: It would be difficult to reproduce.  And I don't see why you would **need** to reproduce it.  The real take-away is that it is possible for strange things to happen if you use a `HashSet` without proper synchronization ... and you shouldn't do it!

Comment: I want to reproduce to to verify this theory of duplicates.
Per suggestion from hfontanez below, I tried to write a test program but seeing a weird behavior.
I see the size is greater than 1 but when I try to print the item, it just prints one. I have uploaded the sample file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awHCrL9RUdniNnhp7IYVIemXuQXMSkL7/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: OK.  Whatever.  I just don't understand why you need to verify this theory.  The possibility of unspecified behavior in this kind of situation is clearly stated in the Java Language Specification.  That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

We can discuss this answer part by part:

1. HashSet does not allow duplicate `elements` which means you can not store duplicate values in HashSet. And its alternative Hashmap doesn't allow `duplicate keys` however, it allows `duplicate values`.
2. `HashSet` in Java is not thread-safe as it is not synchronized by default. If you are using HashSet in a multi-threaded environment where it is accessed by multiple threads concurrently and structurally modified too by even a single thread then it must be synchronized externally. A structural modification is defined as any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.

   So, when you update `HashSet` from multiple threads without external sync, its behavior will be unpredictable.
3. To avoid this unpredictable behavior, we can synchronize HashSet by using Collections.synchronizedSet() method.

Example:

- First, we’ll see an example what happens if HashSet is used in a multi-threaded environment without synchronizing it.

  In the Java code four threads are created, each of these thread adds 5 elements to the Set. After all the threads are done `Set size should be 20`.

```
public class SetSynchro implements Runnable{
  private Set<String> numSet;
  public SetSynchro(Set<String> numSet){
    this.numSet = numSet;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> numSet = new HashSet<String>();
    /// 4 threads
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
        
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
        
    try {
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
      t3.join();
      t4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {    
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Size of Set is " + numSet.size());
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("in run method" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    String str = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      // adding thread name to make element unique
      numSet.add(i + str);
      try {
        // delay to verify thread interference
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
in run methodThread-2
in run methodThread-0
in run methodThread-3
in run methodThread-1
Size of Set is 19
//In one of the run size was 19, in another run 18 and sometimes even 20, so you can see that thread interference is making the behavior unpredictable.
```

- So you can see that thread interference is making the behavior unpredictable. So we’ll synchronize the HashSet using the same example.

```
public class SetSynchro implements Runnable{
  private Set<String> numSet;

  public SetSynchro(Set<String> numSet){
    this.numSet = numSet;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Synchronized Set
    Set<String> numSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
    /// 4 threads
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new SetSynchro(numSet));
    
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
        
    try {
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
      t3.join();
      t4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {    
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Size of Set is " + numSet.size());
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("in run method" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    String str = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      // adding thread name to make element unique
      numSet.add(i + str);
      try {
        // delay to verify thread interference
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
in run methodThread-3
in run methodThread-2
in run methodThread-1
in run methodThread-0
Size of Set is 20
//Now every time size of HashSet is 20.
```

For more details, this [link](https://knpcode.com/java/collections/how-to-synchronize-hashset-in-java/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20synchronize,backed%20by%20the%20specified%20set.) is useful. The code block is also taken from there.

Comment: Thanks for the details but I was more interested on the code where you have come across specifically the usecase of duplicates in similar multithreaded conditions.

Comment: This situation is not predictable. It may be happened or maybe not. So, it is very difficult to say :)

Answer (score 0):

From Javadoc

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
> access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads
> modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally. This is
> typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally
> encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set should be
> "wrapped" using the `Collections.synchronizedSet` method. This is best
> done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to
> the set:
>
> `Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));`

Basically, the way that I interpret this, is that under the right (or wrong) conditions, there might be a slight possibility that this could happen. HOWEVER, since the assumption is that you know that multiple threads will access this set, you need to synchronize access externally (since `HashSet` is not thread-safe). OR, in the absence of such external mechanism, you will need to wrap this set as shown above.

If you really want to find out, create an application with a lot of threads that attempt to set the same value. After insertion, print out some message to the console if the size of the set is ever greater than 1. That should tell you the answer. Maybe the chances of this happening are very small. But the class documentation tells you that if you expect to use in multithreaded process, you should synchronize it.

Comment: Thanks much. I was looking for similar way to kind of reproduce this. I can very well try this.

Comment: I tried a sample program like you suggested but I see the size is greater than 1 but when I try to print the item, it just prints one. I have uploaded the sample file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awHCrL9RUdniNnhp7IYVIemXuQXMSkL7/view?usp=sharing). Could you please suggest why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: @PratikShekhar that's the answer to your question. It is not possible to add the same value to a `HashSet` even in multithreading application.